# Jammy latest updates - Login issues on lock screen - spinning wheels

Tags: login

Anyone noticed issues with gnome/GUI login post latest updates for kernel. I have to key in password multiple times to get through

Linux PC-X  5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you lock the screen and went away for few mins. Come back trying to login (i.e on lock screen) it just keep spinning.. and nothing happens.. key in password again at least 3- 6 times  and probably at 6th time you have a luck.